How to handle multiple interrupts connected on same interrupt line in STM32?
I have created a circuit to use multiple interrupts in STM32H63 microcontroller. e.g. several interrupt sources are conntected to EXTI0 and similarly for others interrupt lines as well. Now, I know that all GPIO interrupt lines are muxed to single EXTI0 line. I generated the code with the help of Cumbe MX IDE.
Now, I have two questions:

Is there any way to distinguish the interrupt source (PA0?
If I some how (through program) make sure that only one source generate the interrupt at a time then do I need to do more configuration in SYSCFG register to make sure that correct GPIO is selected or generated code takes care of it?

I tried to configure the pins for multiple interrupts using CubeMX but it was not allowing to do so.
Thanks in advance.
With Regards
Sachin Sharma

several interrupt sources are conntected to EXTI0 You can't do that, only one Px0 pin is connected to EXTI0 at one time.
